# Best way to convert .Rmd file into .pdf file

Tags: r, knitr

I Have a problem with combining TexMaker, Texworks with R so that I can have my .Rmd files in pdf by knit.
I have installed texmaker and MikteX client, but only if I want to compile my knit into .pdf I get my knit in  .html with following warning :

[image: enter code here]

[image]

Can you give me hand with solving the problem or with giving me some page/pdf where can I read more about compiling TexMaker, Texworks so that my .Rmd files can be successfully complied to pdf ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by R not being able to find your system installation of LaTex. However, you could just install `tinytex`!

This is easily done with `tinytex::install_tinytex` (which is even suggested in your error). If that doesn't work, `tinytex` also offers `tinytex::reinstall_tinytex` which fixes most installations.

Comment: what if both don't work ? tinytex::reinstal_tinytex() gives me information : Error in system2("tlmgr", args, ...) : '"tlmgr"' not found

Comment: @John What happened when you `tinytex::install_tinytex()`? (`reinstall_tinytex()` works only when you have already installed TinyTeX, and you haven't in this case) If that doesn't work, try `tinytex:::install_prebuilt()`.

Comment: Unfortunately the last one also is not working. It gives information 
Warning message:
In extract(path, exdir = path.expand(dirname(default_inst()))) :
  error -1 in extracting from zip file

Comment: Did you restart your R session after installing?